# HTML5 video tag display

Tags: html, video, html5-video

So this is weird. I was experimenting with html5 video tag. Your snapshot photo of the trailer is defined by `video poster="megafon2.png" width="640" height="360"`

Why is the second video smaller than the first? I thought the video will be the dimensions of the poster image you define. If I remove the width and height, you will see the second video go bigger. Maybe is it because of the video format? Is it more like a square?

http://www.2kfilms.com/services_megafon.html

Answer (score 0):

The two videos are both bigger than the space allocated for the `<video>` element (1280x720 and 720x576 respectively) so the browser will attempt to scale them to fit.

For the math to fit it means that the second video ends up being adjusted more.

If you align the size of the media element closer to the source video(s) so the aspect ratio can be maintained while scaling you should see a more consistent result